# Reading real-time value from HTML element in URL page using jQuery

Tags: javascript, url, getelementbyid, currency-exchange-rates

I've got this website: https://coinyep.com/he/ex/ETH-ILS

Inside this URL web page, there is an input element, and its HTML id is: "coinyep-input2".

I need to read its value (= approximately 637.49 ILS) using jQuery in **Visual Studio**.

So far, I tried everything, no success.
Any help will be appreciated.

For example, in jQuery there is a command :

```
 document.getElementById("coinyep-input2");
```

==> I need to do the same thing but to do it from the URL page in order to get values in real-time (exchange rates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I found solution in C# (server), using it by Razor on the client 
[Based on RSS URL]:

```
   public float getExchangeRate_ETH_To_ILS()
    {
        float exchangeRate;
        string[] words;
        int indexOfExchangeRate;

        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            try
            {
                var htmlPage = client.DownloadString("https://coinyep.com/he/rss/ETH-ILS.xml");
                words = htmlPage.Split(' ');
                indexOfExchangeRate = words.IndexOf("ILS");
                exchangeRate = (float)Convert.ToDouble(words[indexOfExchangeRate - 1]);

            }
             catch(Exception e)
             {                        
                exchangeRate = -1;
             }
        }
        return exchangeRate;
    }
```

in the client, I use this fucntion via model (Razor):

```
  var cal1 = @Model.getExchangeRate_ETH_To_ILS();
```

But there is a risk: if the template of the RSS will be changed, we are in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
$("#coinyep-input2").attr("data-valuta");
```

or

```
$("#coinyep-input2").attr("data-value");
```

or

```
$("#coinyep-input2").val();
```

Comment: Where am I suppose to paste the URL?

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I don't understand your question. I pasted my suggested solutions into the developer console and I got the value.

Comment: I`m trying to read it using Visual Studio.... into jQuery function.

Comment: My goal is to read this value and use it in Visual Studio. If it is possible in HTML to use <img> element with src which is actually a URL, there must be a way to read a value from the input text element.

Comment: I tried to explain my goal, hope you will understand

Comment: I think you are talking about scraping the page? You can use a page scraper like cheerio.js or use an API that holds that data. Hope this helps.

Comment: Its seems that cheerio.js works with VSCODE. I need it for VS2019.

Comment: This link might help: [link](https://www.garethjames.net/a-guide-to-web-scrapping-tools/)